# how to get dataIndex by column index in ExtJS 6/7

Tags: extjs, extjs7

This works in old versions:

```
var dataIndex = grid.getHeaderCt().getHeaderAtIndex(columnIndex).dataIndex;
```

I need the exact functionality for ExtJS 7.

I noticed that in newer versions you can get the header with grid.getHeader(), but I can't find any method from Ext.panel.Header that could give me the dataIndex.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways to get the dataIndex from grid using indexes. Below are some of them:

```
grid.getHeaderContainer().getHeaderAtIndex(index).dataIndex;

grid.getColumnManager().getHeaderAtIndex(index).dataIndex;

grid.getColumns()[index].dataIndex;
```

You should not look in `Ext.panel.Header` as it contains configs related to the grids header containing the title. Instead look in `Ext.grid.header.Container` which will have configs related to grid column headers. Refer the documentation link:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.grid.header.Container.html

Comment: Great response. Thanks!